# Why is my scheme program not combining my two list correctly at the end?

Tags: scheme, racket

```
(define unzip (lambda (l)

            (define front (lambda (a)

            (if (null? a)
                '()
                 (cons (car (car a)) (unzip (cdr a)))
            )))

            (define back (lambda (b)
                           (if (null? b)
                               '()
                               (cons (car (cdr (car b))) (unzip (cdr b)))
                            )))
            (list (front l) (back l))))
```

(unzip '((1 2) (3 4) (5 6)))

this call is supposed to return ((1 3 5) (2 4 6))
and if I replace the last line of code "(list (front l) (back l)) with just (front l) or (back l) i get the correct lists but i cant seem to put them together it justs keeps spitting out weird outputs every time i try.

Comment: It is not clear what the function should produce. What is the result of `(unzip '((2 3 7) (3 4 8)(5 6 9)))` for example? And `(unzip '((2) (3))` (your function gives an error)? Giving only a single example without describing what the function should return makes difficult to propose a solution.

Comment: sorry i changed it to what it was supposed to be in the question (unzip (2 3) (8 7)) -> ((2 8) (3 7))

Comment: I guess everybody knows that `zip` can be simplified to `(define (zip . l) 
  (apply map list l))` ?

Answer (score 2):

Your code structure is very unconventional and I suspect you're rather new to scheme/racket. Your procedure can be written in a much more idiomatic way.

The first criticism I'd probably make about your code is that it makes the assumption that the lists you're unzipping will only have 2 elements each.

- What about unzipping 3 lists of 5 elements or 5 lists of 3 elements ?
- What about unzipping 4 lists of 4 elemens ?
- What about unzipping 1 list of 7 elements or 7 lists of 1 element ?
- What about unzipping nothing ?

These questions all point to a fundamental concept that helps shape well-structured procedures:

***"What is a "total" procedure ?"***

A **total procedure** is one that is defined for all values of an accepted type. What that means to us is that, if we write an `unzip` procedure, it should

- accept an empty list
- accept any number of lists
- accept lists of any length<sup>1</sup>

Let's take a look at an `unzip` procedure that does that now. It's likely this procedure can be improved, but at the very least, it's easy to read and comprehend

```
(define (unzip xs (ys empty))
  ; if no xs are given, return ys
  (cond [(empty? xs) empty]
        ; if the first input is empty, return the final answer; reversed
        [(empty? (car xs)) (reverse ys)]
        ; otherwise, unzip the tail of each xs, and attach each head to ys
        [else (unzip (map cdr xs) (cons (map car xs) ys))]))

(unzip '((1 2) (3 4) (5 6)))

; => '((1 3 5) (2 4 6))
```

Let's step through the evaluation.

```
; initial call
(unzip '((1 2) (3 4) (5 6)))

; (empty? xs) nope
; (empty? (car xs)) nope
; (unzip (map cdr xs) (cons (map car xs) ys))

; substitue values
(unzip (map cdr '((1 2) (3 4) (5 6)))
       (cons (map car '((1 2) (3 4) (5 6))) empty))

; eval (map cdr xs)
(unzip '((2) (4) (6))
       (cons (map car '((1 2) (3 4) (5 6))) empty))

; eval (map car xs)
(unzip '((2) (4) (6))
       (cons '(1 3 5) empty))

; eval cons
; then recurse unzip
(unzip '((2) (4) (6))
       '((1 3 5)))

; (empty? xs) nope
; (empty? (car xs)) nope
; (unzip (map cdr xs) (cons (map car xs) ys))

; substitue values
(unzip (map cdr '((2) (4) (6)))
       (cons (map car '((2) (4) (6))) '((1 3 5))))

; eval (map cdr xs)
(unzip '(() () ())
       (cons (map car '((2) (4) (6))) '((1 3 5))))

; eval (map car xs)
(unzip '(() () ())
       (cons '(2 4 5) '((1 3 5))))

; eval cons
; then recurse
(unzip '(() () ())
       '((2 4 5) (1 3 5)))

; (empty? xs) nope
; (empty? (car xs)) yup!
; (reverse ys)

; substituion
(reverse '((2 4 5) (1 3 5)))

; return
'((1 3 5) (2 4 5))
```

Here's another thing to think about. Did you notice that `unzip` is basically doing the same thing as `zip` ? Let's look at your input little closer

```
'((1 2)
  (3 4)
  (5 6))
   ^ ^
```

Look at the columns. If we were to `zip` these, we'd get

```
'((1 3 5) (2 4 6))
```

***"Wait, so do you mean that a `unzip` is just another `zip` and vice versa ?"***

Yup.

```
(unzip '((1 2) (3 4) (5 6)))
; => '((1 3 5) (2 4 6))

(unzip (unzip '((1 2) (3 4) (5 6))))
; '((1 2) (3 4) (5 6))

(unzip (unzip (unzip '((1 2) (3 4) (5 6)))))
; '((1 3 5) (2 4 6))
```

Knowing this, if you already had a `zip` procedure, your definition to `unzip` becomes insanely easy

```
(define unzip zip)
```

Which basically means:

**You don't need an `unzip` procedure**, just re-`zip` it

```
(zip '((1 2) (3 4) (5 6)))
; => '((1 3 5) (2 4 6))

(zip (zip '((1 2) (3 4) (5 6))))
; '((1 2) (3 4) (5 6))

(zip (zip (zip '((1 2) (3 4) (5 6)))))
; '((1 3 5) (2 4 6))
```

Anyway, I'm guessing your `unzip` procedure implementation is a bit of homework. The long answer your professor is expecting is probably something along the lines of the procedure I originally provided. The sneaky answer is `(define unzip zip)`

---

***"So is this `unzip` procedure considered a total procedure ?"***

- What about unzipping 3 lists of 5 elements or 5 lists of 3 elements ?

  ```
  (unzip '((a b c d e) (f g h i j) (k l m n o p)))
  ; => '((a f k) (b g l) (c h m) (d i n) (e j o))

  (unzip '((a b c) (d e f) (g h i) (k l m) (n o p)))
  ; => '((a d g k n) (b e h l o) (c f i m p))
  ```
- What about unzipping 4 lists of 4 elemens ?

  ```
  (unzip '((a b c d) (e f g h) (i j k l) (m n o p)))
  ; => '((a e i m) (b f j n) (c g k o) (d h l p))
  ```
- What about unzipping 1 list of 7 elements or 7 lists of 1 element ?

  ```
  (unzip '((a b c d e f g)))
  ; => '((a) (b) (c) (d) (e) (f) (g))

  (unzip '((a) (b) (c) (d) (e) (f) (g)))
  ; => '((a b c d e f g))
  ```
- What about unzipping nothing ?

  ```
  (unzip '())
  ; => '()
  ```
- What about unzipping 3 empty lists ?

  ```
  (unzip '(() () ()))
  ; => '()
  ```

> <sup>**1**</sup> We said that `unzip` should "accept lists of any length" but we're bending the rules just a little bit here. It's true that `unzip` accepts lists of any length, but it's also true that each list much be the same length as the others. For lists of varying length, an objective "correct" solution is not possible and for this lesson, we'll leave the behavior for mixed-length lists as *undefined*.
>
> ```
> ; mixed length input is undefined
> (unzip '((a) (b c d) (e f))) ; => ???
> ```

---

**A couple side notes**

Things like

```
(car (car x))
(car (cdr (car x)))
```

Can be simplified to

```
(caar x)
(cadar x)
```

The following [pair accessor short-hand procedures](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28part._.Pair_.Accessor_.Shorthands%29) exist

```
caar    ; (car (car x))
cadr    ; (car (cdr x))
cdar    ; (cdr (car x))
cddr    ; (cdr (cdr x))
caaar   ; (car (car (car x)))
caadr   ; (car (car (cdr x)))
cadar   ; (car (cdr (car x)))
caddr   ; (car (cdr (cdr x)))
cdaar   ; (cdr (car (car x)))
cdadr   ; (cdr (car (cdr x)))
cddar   ; (cdr (cdr (car x)))
cdddr   ; (cdr (cdr (cdr x)))
caaaar  ; (car (car (car (car x))))
caaadr  ; (car (car (car (cdr x))))
caadar  ; (car (car (cdr (car x))))
caaddr  ; (car (car (cdr (cdr x))))
cadaar  ; (car (cdr (car (car x))))
cadadr  ; (car (cdr (car (cdr x))))
caddar  ; (car (cdr (cdr (car x))))
cadddr  ; (car (cdr (cdr (cdr x))))
cdaaar  ; (cdr (car (car (car x))))
cdaadr  ; (cdr (car (car (cdr x))))
cdadar  ; (cdr (car (cdr (car x))))
cdaddr  ; (cdr (car (cdr (cdr x))))
cddaar  ; (cdr (cdr (car (car x))))
cddadr  ; (cdr (cdr (car (cdr x))))
cdddar  ; (cdr (cdr (cdr (car x))))
cddddr  ; (cdr (cdr (cdr (cdr x))))
```

Comment: `unzip` and `zip` are not the same procedure since they take in their arguments differently. `(define (unzip lsts) (apply zip lsts))`

Comment: @Sylwester that's an API detail though. `(define (zip lsts) ...)` could be made to be a totally valid procedure. I'm not aware of any racket built-in `zip` procedure, so perhaps it's fair to say that this is a matter of preference ?

Comment: You have the [SRFI-1 List library](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html) which is one of the supported [SRFI's in #!racket, #!r6rs, and perhaps more languages in the racket system](http://docs.racket-lang.org/srfi/)

Answer (score 0):

It is combining the lists correctly, but it's not combining the correct lists.

Extracting the local definitions makes them testable in isolation:

```
(define (front a)
  (if (null? a)
      '()
      (cons (car (car a)) (unzip (cdr a)))))

(define (back b)
  (if (null? b)
      '()
      (cons (car (cdr (car b))) (unzip (cdr b)))))


(define (unzip l)
    (list (front l) (back l)))

(define test '((1 2) (3 4) (5 6)))
```

Test:

```
> (front test)
'(1 (3 (5 () ()) (6 () ())) (4 (5 () ()) (6 () ())))
> (front '((1 2)))         
'(1 () ())
> (back '((1 2)))
'(2 () ())
```

Weird...

```
> (unzip '())
'(() ())
> (unzip '((1 2)))
'((1 () ()) (2 () ()))
```

It looks like *something* is correct, but the lists' tails are wrong.

If you look carefully at the definitions of `front` and `back`, they're recursing to `unzip`.
But they should recurse to themselves - `front` is the "first first" followed by the rest of the "firsts", and `back` is the "first second" followed by the rest of the "seconds".
`unzip` has nothing to do with this.

```
(define (front a)
  (if (null? a)
      '()
      (cons (car (car a)) (front (cdr a)))))

(define (back b)
  (if (null? b)
      '()
      (cons (car (cdr (car b))) (back (cdr b)))))
```

And now...

```
> (front test)
'(1 3 5)
> (back test)
'(2 4 6)
> (unzip test)
'((1 3 5) (2 4 6))
```